# Is it a problem If I keep my nft meta data ipfs link public?

Tags: nft, smart-contract-wallets, ipfs, opensea, meta-data

So I have deployed a nft smart contract. And I kept my ipfs metadata address public. Is it a major issue? Should I verify my samart contract?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IPFS just describes the token's essential properties, nothing secret there.

As long as the private key of your deploying wallet is hidden safely, you should be OK.

Verifying your smart contract will help with gaining trust from other users, shouldn't matter in terms of your NFT's security.